# Can I have separate category slug and title for a Jekyll blog?

Tags: jekyll

I am building a Jekyll website where I will have categorized pages. A page might have a category called "Introduction to programming" but I want the category slug to be "cse110" so as to keep my URLs short.

Is there any way I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use **cse110** as category. That should take care of the URL part. 
Now for the title, write a condition that whenever the category is cse110, it should show "Introduction to Programming"

```
{% if page.categories == 'cse110' %}
<span>Introsuction to Programming</span>
{% endif %}
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: Thank you. However, that is going to turn into a lot of lines of code since there will be many categories. Is that the only way it can be done in Jekyll?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the permlink in the frontmatter to manipulate the output directory. Your category page will look something like this:

```
---
title: Introduction to programming
permalink: /cse110/
---
```